# Two Var AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have created an email with the following code:

```
<!-- Model-->
%%[
  
var @Description
If Description == 'Model1' then
set @Description = 'Model1'
elseif Value == 'N-' then
set @Description = "Model1-N"


OR
var @Description
If Description == 'Model2' then
set @Description = 'Model2'
elseif Value == 'N-' then
set @Description = "Model2-N"


OR
  
var @Description
elseif Description == [Description] then
set @Description = [Description]
elseif Value == '' then
set @Description = [Description]

endif
]%%
```

I need to have differents texts for other models.For example: model1, model2, model3 with value o without value.

I have two variables in the Data Extension that have to be joined (Description and value) but there are some of the Data Extension users that have description but not value or both (descripcion and value)  EJ: Model1, Model1-N, Model2, Model2-N

But, i don't know that I use correctly or

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please be more precise on the logic you want to implement, as your code is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LukasLunow commented, your current code is strewn with syntax errors.  If I understand your request, what you want is something like the below:

```
%%[

SET @description = AttributeValue("description")
SET @value = AttributeValue("value")

IF @description == "Model1" THEN
  /* Model1 Info */
ELSEIF @description == "Model2" THEN
  /* Model1-N Info */
ELSEIF @description == "Model3" THEN
  /* Model2 Info */
ELSEIF @description == "Model4" THEN
  /* Model2-N Info */
ELSE
  /* Default Info */
ENDIF

IF NOT EMPTY(@value) THEN
 SET @modelname = CONCAT(@description,@value)
ENDIF

]%%
/* Output Model info HTML */
```

When you output variables, you will want to use the inline syntax of `%%=v(@var)=%%` to output, where `@var` is the set variable you made.

What I would recommend is having the same variable for each model set as it is inside of an if statement, it will only be run once.

So for example:

```
%%[
...
IF @description == "Model1" THEN
  SET @modelname = "Model1"
  SET @modeldisclaimer = "* This model is version 1 so it may not be as cool as newer models."
  SET @modelCopy = "This is the original and retro version. Super cool!*"
ELSEIF ....
ENDIF
/* Where ... is your other code */

IF NOT EMPTY(@value) THEN
 SET @modelname = CONCAT(@description,@value)
ENDIF
]%%

<h1>Thank you for buying %%=v(@modelname)=%%!</h1>
<p>%%=v(@modelCopy)=%%</p>
<p>%%=v(@modeldisclaimer)=%%</p>
```

Which would output: (assuming description is Model1)

> **Thank you for buying Model1!**
> This is the original and retro version. Super cool!*
> * This model is version 1 so it may not be as cool as newer models.

OR

Which would output: (assuming description is Model1 and value is '-N')

> **Thank you for buying Model1-N!**
> This is the original and retro version. Super cool!*
> * This model is version 1 so it may not be as cool as newer models.

If value needs to be shifted or adjusted and cannot be simply concat, then you would just add in ELSEIF conditions, etc. similar to what you have for description already.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I didn't explain well, what I mean is that I have two variables in the Data Extension that have to be joined (Description and value) but there are some of the Data Extension users that have description but not value. EJ: Model1, Model1-N, Model2, Model2-N...

Comment: edited to add in requirements from comments.